# Generate IN statement for decimal values with Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm having trouble getting LINQ to generate an IN statement.  I have a function that looks like the one below, taking as input a list of long representing the primary keys to find.  Using the contains methods ends up generating a query of composite OR statements.  We're running against an Oracle database. We're using the newest version of LINQ/EF.  QueryableDbSet is a DbSet.  The PrimaryKey property is a decimal value and is the primary integer identifier for the object in Oracle.

```
List<long> GetList(List<long> ids)
{
    List<decimal> dIds = ids.Select(x => (decimal)x);
    var query = from c in QueryableDbSet
                where dIds.Contains(c.PrimaryKey)
                select (long)c;
    return query.ToList();
}
```

The above code will generate composite OR statements.  Does any one know how to get LINQ to generate the faster IN statements?  Thanks.

EDIT:  Doing some more research it appears that Oracle actually converts IN statements to OR chains, so maybe this is an exercise in futility. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Also, I'm aware that the above function is completely pointless/redundant.  My real use case is more complicated and involves other conditionals in the where clause.

Comment: Is there a query analyzer in Oracle where you can examine the execution plans for the SQL you want LINQ to generate and the SQL it actually generates? If so then you could use that to determine if you're gaining anything by using IN instead of OR.

Comment: Just an FYI, Linq to Sql is not the same thing as Entity Framework.  They're two different frameworks.

Comment: Per your update - I believe (most of the time) that IN is just syntactic sugar for composite ORs. SQL Server that is certainly the case. There are a few edge cases when the optimizer will use a different method to accomplish an IN but they are rare.

Comment: @MystereMan I know they're not the same technologies, but I am using both of them.

Comment: @mhand - how are you using both?  Linq to sql only supports SQL Server, not oracle.

Comment: Remember, Oracle "IN" is limited to 1000 items.